# Parsing Google Earth KML file in Python (lxml, namespaces)

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, xml-namespaces

I am trying to parse a [.kml](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/) file into Python using the xml module (after failing to make this work in BeautifulSoup, which I use for HTML).

As this is my first time doing this, I followed the official [tutorial](http://lxml.de/1.3/tutorial.html) and all goes well until I try to construct an iterator to extract my data by root iteration:

```
from lxml import etree
tree=etree.parse('kmlfile')
```

Here is the [example](http://lxml.de/1.3/tutorial.html#tree-iteration) from the tutorial I am trying to emulate:

> If you know you are only interested in a single tag, you can pass its name to getiterator() to have it filter for you:
>
> ```
> for element in root.getiterator("child"):
>     print element.tag, '-', element.text
> ```

I would like to get all data under 'Placemark', so  I tried

```
for i in tree.getiterterator("Placemark"):
    print i, type(i)
```

which doesn't give me anything. What does work is:

```
for i in tree.getiterterator("{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Placemark"):
    print i, type(i)
```

I don't understand how this comes about. The www.opengis.net is listed in the  tag at the beginning of the document (*kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"...*) , but I don't understand

- how the part in {} relates to my specific example at all
- why it is different from the tutorial
- and what I am doing wrong

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You should take the time to read up on XML namespaces in general (there's [a very nice and comprehensive write-up on the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx)) and [how XML namespaces are represented by Element Tree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm), which lxml emulates (also see "Clark’s notation", for historic context). Further reading, for a way out of this mess: The [lxml documentation on doing XPath with namespaces](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes).

Comment: thanks for your help! ill take a look at those.

Comment: @Tomalak These helped a lot, thanks! If I understand correctly, the part in *{}* above is the default namespace; it is defined as such in the *<kml>* tag at the beginning and does not need to be included afterwards. However, one thing is still unclear to me: In the [tutorial on XPath](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes), the author states that *XPath does not have a notion of a default namespace.* Then how would I deal with it in XPath? The author shows how to set up namespaces in a dictionary, but I can't see how that would work for the default that has no prefix? Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. The "default namespace" nothing but is a convenience facility in XML to cut down on the number of times you have to write a certain prefix. Namespace prefixes *themselves* are nothing but a convenience facility to cut down on the number of times you have to write a namespace URI.

Comment: An XML node is attached to its namespace URI. Node name and Namespace URI are an inseparable union. If you want to select a certain node, you **have to** know its URI. You can do it explicitly, like etree does it in its proprietary `{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Placemark` notation, or implicitly, by assigning a handle ("prefix") to a URI and then using that handle, like XPath does it. You are free to choose whatever handle you like, you don't have to use the same handle that was in the XML. Go ahead and register `kml` as `http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2` and use `kml` in your XPath queries.

Comment: Imagine namespaces as colors. You could assign the handle `red` to the color code `#FF0000`. XML even has a facility to define a default color for all elements that don't have their own color defined. When querying the XML through XPath you must specify the color. XPath knows nothing about the "default color" mechanism that XML provides, you must either query explicitly `car[namespace-uri() = '#FF0000']` or tell XPath up-front that `#FF0000` shall be known as `red` so that you can query `red:car`.

Comment: thanks for these detailed comments. this really helped me, and I'll give that 'assigning a prefix to the default' a shot. i really appreciate the time and effort you put into this, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. You can repay it by posting the solution you ended up using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my solution.
So, the most important thing to do is read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx) as posted by Tomalak. It's a really good description of namespaces and easy to understand.

We are going to use [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) to navigate the XML document. Its notation is similar to file systems, where parents and descendants are separated by slashes */*. The syntax is explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp), but note that some commands are different for the [lxml implementation](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XPath-class.html).

###Problem

Our goal is to extract the city name: the content of `<name>` which is under `<Placemark>`. Here's the relevant XML:

```
<Placemark> <name>CITY NAME</name>
```

The XPath equivalent to the non-functional code I posted above is:

```
tree=etree.parse('kml document')
result=tree.xpath('//Placemark/name/text()')
```

Where the `text()` part is needed to get the text contained in the location `//Placemark/name`.

Now this doesn't work, as Tomalak pointed out, cause the name of these two nodes are actually `{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Placemark` and `{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}name`. The part in curly brackets is the default namespace. It does not show up in the actual document (which confused me) but it is defined at the beginning of the XML document like this:

```
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
```

###Solution

We can supply namespaces to xpath by setting the `namespaces` argument:

```
xpath(X, namespaces={prefix: namespace})
```

This is easy enough for the namespaces that have actual prefixes, in this document for instance `<gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>` where the `gx` prefix is defined in the document as `xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"`.

However, Xpath does not understand what a default namespace is (cf [docs](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html)). Therefore, we need to trick it, like Tomalak suggested above: We invent a prefix for the default and add it to our search terms. We can just call it kml for instance. This piece of code actually does the trick:

```
tree.xpath('//kml:Placemark/kml:name/text()', namespaces={"kml":"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"})
```

The [tutorial](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html) mentions that there is also an [ETXPath](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.ETXPath-class.html) method, that works just like Xpath except that one writes the namespaces out in curly brackets instead of defining them in a dictionary. Thus, the input would be of the style `{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}Placemark`.

Comment: XPath link is dead

Comment: Hm worked for me today

Comment: Huh works now. Maybe that site was down