# Find Placemarks in kml file

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I want to find all the Placemarks in a kml file:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse(filename)
for elem in doc.findall('<Placemark>'):
   print(elem.find("<Placemark>").text)
```

This doesn't work, i.e. it doesn't find anything, I think because each Placemark is unique in that each has its own id, e.g.:

```
<Placemark id="ID_09795">
<Placemark id="ID_15356">
<Placemark id="ID_64532">
```

How do I do this?

Edit: changed code based on @ScottHunter comment:

```
placemark_list = doc.findall("Placemark")
print ("length:" + str(len(placemark_list)))
for placemark in placemark_list:
  print(placemark.text)
```

length is 0

Comment: Shouldn't each `elem` *be* a `Placemark`?  Why do you need to do another `find` in the `print` statement?

Comment: Can we see a sample of your kml file?

Comment: @ScottHunter: see addition to question

Comment: I guess that the XML document uses a namespace. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38189578/407651

Comment: That solution doesn't use lxml unfortunately

Comment: What? The answer to the linked question does use lxml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the full file, but try something like this

```
placemark_list = doc.xpath("//*[local-name()='Placemark']")
print(len(placemark_list))
```

and see if it works.